# Modular functions and elliptic functions

Tags: elliptic-curves, modular-forms

Does anybody know of an equation formally equating modular functions and elliptic functions similar to Euler's equation for exponential and trigonometric functions?

Any advice much appreciated.

Thanks,

-A

Answer (score 8):

I don't really understand what this means; modular functions and elliptic functions don't even have the same domain, although they are closely related.

A modular function is a meromorphic function on the upper half-plane $\mathbb{H}$ which is invariant under the action of the modular group $\Gamma = \text{SL}_2(\mathbb{Z})$. The corresponding quotient can be thought of as the moduli space of elliptic curves in a certain way. In other words, a modular function is something like an invariant of elliptic curves.

An elliptic function, on the other hand, is a meromorphic function on the complex plane $\mathbb{C}$ which is invariant under the action of a lattice $\Lambda = \mathbb{Z} \omega_1 \oplus \mathbb{Z} \omega_2$. The corresponding quotient can be thought of as a *particular* elliptic curve. In other words, an elliptic function is simply a function on a *particular* elliptic curve.

Your confusion probably stems from the fact that there are elliptic functions, such as the [Weierstrass $\wp$ function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass%27s_elliptic_functions), which can be uniformly defined for different elliptic curves, and hence which *also* allow us to define modular functions. This is because the Weierstrass function has more structure than just being an elliptic function; it is also a [Jacobi form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobi_form).

The analogy to trigonometric functions seems to fall short: elliptic functions are analogous to trigonometric functions, but there isn't a good notion of "modular function" here since the moduli space of circles is a point.

Comment: Maybe what's going on here is this: elliptic curves can be parametrized by elliptic functions. They can also be parametrized by modular functions. So maybe the question is asking for a relation between the elliptic functions parametrizing a given elliptic curve and the modular functions parametrizing that curve.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure this question makes sense.  Both $e^z$ and $\sin(z)$ are functions of one complex variable. Modular forms like $E_k(\tau)$ are functions of one variable (belonging to the upper half-plane $H$). Elliptic functions like $\wp(z,\tau)$ are either a functions of two variables for variable $\tau$, (i.e., functions on $\mathbb{C} \times H$, or a bi-periodic functions of $z$ on the complex plane for a fixed $\tau_0$; and hence can not be expressed in terms of the modular forms which are functions on the upper half plane.

However, if you take a Laurent series of $\wp(z,\tau)$ in $z$, you will see that the coefficients are modular forms in $\tau$, indeed.